# Is there a point to handle exceptions in selenium besides for logging purposes?

Tags: java, selenium, exception, appium

I am finding it hard to understand the point of exception handling in selenium.
For example, if I try to click on an element, and the element could not be found then `NoSuchElementException` occurs. 
I can catch the exception, throw new `RunTimeException`, or do nothing. The result will be the same ( the program will fail and stop ).

Why would I bother to handle such an exception?

Am I missing something here?

thanks

```
    public void clickOnElement(MobileElement element, Integer waitInSeconds){
    waitInSeconds = (waitInSeconds != null ? waitInSeconds : this.secondsToWait);
    try {
        waitFor(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element),waitInSeconds);
        element.click();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Could not click on element");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you needed to wait for an element thats added after page load (think of a div thats loaded asynchonously), you might want some code to constantly try lookup that element constantly and only return if found, or an amount of time has passed.

Answer (score 2):

Exception handling for Selenium is a great way to proof your tests against unexpected conditions. For example, you can try to find the element again if it is no longer attached to the page, for example after a javascript is executed that changes something in the element.

```
try{
    driver.findElement(By.id("MyId")).click();
} catch (StaleElementReferenceException e){
    driver.findElement(By.id("MyId")).click();
}
```

Or, for example, you can ignore if an element does not appear, for example, a GDPR overlay at the top of the page after logging in.

```
try {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("gdpr_overlay")));
} catch (TimeoutException ignored){

}
```

This will ignore the exception thrown by the wait if the overlay does not appear and continue to run your test.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are very useful features, far more useful than just for logging, you should look it up.
You can do whatever you want in the catch block, you can try to click a different element if the first one failed, redirect to another page... The possibilities are endless really.
Advice: Avoid generic exceptions, you should catch specific exceptions and react accordingly, and in the last catch block you can do generic Exception e and throw an error.

Comment: So basically if I catch the exception and click on another element instead in the catch block, the program will continue to run?

Comment: Sounds a lot like using Exceptions for flow control to me.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly ExceptionHandling is not a concept of Selenium but it is related to JAVA. Now coming to the usage of handling exceptions it has a lot of depth to the concept which you will understand while constructing frameworks but as of now it is important to understand by handling exceptions you can continue to execute your code without JVM terminating the rest when it comes across an exception.

```
try{
}
catch{
}
finally
{
}
```

Finally is also very helpful when you always want to execute a block of code irrespective of whether ur scenario is going to pass or fail for example like driver.close().
Hope that helped ... Happy coding :)